# Plotting points on a graph?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a function and I want to draw points on that function.

For example:

```py
def f(x):
    return x ** 2 + 2 * x + 4

x_val= np.linspace(-6,6)
graph = f(x_val)

plt.plot(x_val, graph)
```

This will give the function evaluated at `x_val`.

I want to plot points on the graph at `f(-2), f(2)` like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plot` with the third parameter being a marker. The different markers can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html). The third parameter of `plot` is a string where the first letter indicates the color ('r' for red, 'g' for green, ...) and the second letter the marker. More information can be found in the [official docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return x ** 2 + 2 * x + 4

x_val= np.linspace(-6,6)
graph = f(x_val)

plt.plot(x_val, graph)
plt.plot(-2, f(-2), 'ro')
plt.plot(2, f(2), 'ro')

plt.show()
```

[image: sample plot]

Answer (score 0):

In case you have several points, you have two options:

- Plot them individually using a for loop
- Plot them all at once using a scatter plot via vectorised operation on a NumPy array of points (shown below)

---

```
points = np.array([-2, 2])

plt.plot(x_val, graph)
plt.scatter(points, f(points), c='r') 
plt.show()
```

[image]